# Getting the error "Error: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1; required keyword: url)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, kimurai

Im building a basic rails web scraper and im running into this error. Here is my scraper method and my scraper model too.

https://gyazo.com/d866cd8def5ac107ea8c13515faac989

```
class RestaurantsScraper < Kimurai::Base
    @name = 'restaurants_scraper'
    @engine = :mechanize


    def self.process(url)
        url = 'tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g31892-Rogers_Arkansas.html'
        @start_url = [url]
        self.crawl!
    end


    def parse(response, url:, data: {})
        response.xpath("//div[@class=_1llCuDZj]").each do |t|
            item = {}
            
            item[:title] = t.css('a._15_ydu6b')&.text&.squish&.gsub('[^0-9].', '')
            item[:type] = t.css('span._1p0FLy4t')&.text&.squish
            item[:reviews] = t.css('span.w726Ki5B').text&.squish
            item[:top_reviews] = t.css('a._2uEVo25r _3mPt7dFq').text&.squish

            Restaurant.where(item).first_or_create
        end
    end

end
```

```
  def scrape
    url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g31892-Rogers_Arkansas.html'
    response = RestaurantsScraper.process(url)
    if response[:status] == :completed && response[:error].nil?
      flash.now[:notice] = "Successfully scraped url"
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = response[:error]
    end
  rescue StandardError => e
    flash.now[:alert] = "Error: #{e}"
  end
```

Comment: Can you change `parse(response, url:, data: {})` to `parse(response, :url, data: {})` and see if that helps?

Comment: @jad Thats will just cause a syntax error further down. Did you mean `parse(response, url, data: {})`? Not sure how that will help as it most likely wont match the signature its being called with.